# I am sure there is electricity from the power supply, but the device won't power up

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, power-supply, power

For someone without an electrical engineering background, I've searched this issue online but couldn't find satisfying answers, so I'm asking it here.

I have had this issue multiple times in the past.

Occasion 1: I have a Lenovo Y50-70 that after plugging the power supply, it blinks a few times then proceeds to not charge at all. After purchasing a new power source, the laptop starts charging/working.

Occasion 2: I have a WD external hard drive that will not spin after plugging in the power supply. However, I hear a continuous sound after plugging in the power source. After fiddling with this for 2 hours (trying the 3.3V pin fix and other sorcery), I decided to try a different power source. Voila, it came back to life.

My question is that clearly there is electricity coming from the power sources (blinking light from Y50-70, and a continuous sound from WD external hard drive), but why is it that the power supply fails to provide power?

Comment: Whether this is a common issue or not is not helpful information for you and makes your question opinion based. I have removed this portion of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A power supply may have issues causing either badly regulated, *low* output (voltage drop when using the full rated current), or poorly-filtered ("dirty") output, with AC noise on what should be a pure DC output. A common cause of both are failing filter capacitors. Devices need *clean* DC of the *required* voltage, and from your description, the power supplies were out of specifications.

You would need to test the supplies **under load**, examining both DC voltage and AC noise level. Someone with electronic test equipment such as an accurate voltmeter, an electronic load or suitable power resistor, and an oscilloscope could do this for you.

Comment: Just to emphasise… Power supplies get 'tired' after a time - this is why the specific need to measure *under load*. Without load, it might give a full 12v, but once loaded that could be down to 3v. Without a meter that can simulate load, you'd never know.

Comment: What is called 'time' above may also include interference that they're not built to endure, e.g. lightning up close or in (what i like to call) "electrical vicinity" may cause damage that makes it misbehave. This kind of damage is hard to fault-find and also repair, such a repaired PSU may fail again after a short time; even causing more damage in subsequent electronics.

Comment: As @Hannu states, a voltage surge can damage parts. At one time, electrolytic capacitors were likely to fail with time, but their reliability has *greatly* improved. Other than those caps, other parts in a power supply, barring surges, accidents or stray cosmic rays [a serious problem in satellites], should last for *decades*.